# Joomla virtuemart how can sort the custom filed values in drop down menu?

Tags: plugins, joomla2.5, custom-fields, virtuemart, dropdownbox

How to sort the custom filed values in drop down menu?

[image: Drop down in virtuemart]

Answer (score 0):

You could use Move option in custom fields tab.

[image]